# toLocaleDateString() returns year with 2 digit instead of 4 in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I  call `toLocaleDateString()` I expected the year in 4 digits like **08/15/2021**

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }) // 08/15/21
```

or

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-Gb') // 08/15/21
```

Comment: In what environment? I get 4 digit year when running in Chrome and Firefox on Windows

Comment: In react-native I'm trying